Fetch API Response via HTTPS
I've created an HTML page and I am retrieving it over HTTPS. Clicking a button on that page sends a Javascript Fetch API request to an HTTPS endpoint, a PHP script I also created.
My question is: if I'm sending the request over HTTPS, will the Fetch API response be automatically returned over HTTPS? Or do I need to do something server-side to ensure the response is returned securely?

If you are accessing a HTTPS url with a standard browser in any way, and that request succeeded then the entire request/response went over HTTPS and was secure.
This is by design because when you use HTTPS you want the guarantee that it can be trusted.

It is not possible to send a request over unsecured HTTP and then receive the response over secure HTTPS, or vice versa. TLS encryption is applied to the connection as a whole before any individual HTTP messages are transmitted. The request and response are transmitted over a single connection.
If you send a request to an http: URL then the connection is unsecured. If you send a request to an https: url then the connection is secured.  If you don't specify the protocol (ie because you are using a relative url) then it will use the same protocol that was used to retrieve the HTML page.

Thank you, Remy. Good info. Much appreciated.
